# Where to put my taglib declaration?

Tags: jsp, jstl

I've got a JSP and I'm going to start using the JSTL taglib. So I need to declare it and I do it by the row

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

But where do I put this code? At the top of the file, before everything, or after imports? Does it matter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually right at the top of the file. If you start using multiple taglibs you could also move it to a separate include file to safe typing. For example

/WEB-INF/jspf/taglibs.jspf

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=utf8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
```

/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp

```
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/jspf/taglibs.jspf" %>
```

Answer (score 2):

I usually put it before anything, even before the <%@ page %>.

Just a little trick to have a cleaner HTML code generated, put them like this:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
%><%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"
%><%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"
%><html>
...
</html>
```

Comment: Please don't do that anymore ! Rather use `<%@ page trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true" %>`

Answer (score 2):

You put the taglib declaration right at the top of the file before everything else.